# Bootstrap 3 and problems with IE8 (acting like mobile) - respond included

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I'm trying to finish this site http://jolaga.laohost.net/topsleva/. Almost all looks good in all normal browsers. But IE8 looks like in mobile mode - all containers are 100% width. 
Respond.js and html5shiv.js are included. Meta  is in head section. I don't know what else should I do ? For sure IE ignores media queries - but I didn't figure out why.

Comment: Did you try to include respond.js not in "if IE" tag?

Comment: I just did it and nothing changed.

Comment: Another issue appear in IE9 if i click on toggle (+) on left categories it's open but if I click again it doesn't hide

Comment: Css3-mediaquerries included. Still not working :(

Comment: Funny thing I noticed that IE8 looks good for resolutions less then 980px. Now I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that bootstrap css was before custom styles. I swapped them and everything works like charm

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark, because i don't have ie7/8 installed at the moment, but here goes:
offhand, it looks like you are targeting less than ie9, so here ie7/8, with ie7.css.
i never use bootstrap, but i'm assuming you are using the regular repo, and not one you've tweaked on your own.
if thats the case, i'm positive that style sheet is only for ie7, and that is why ie8 is all busted up.
you have two options here:
1) get rid of existing conditional comments. create a style sheet for ie8 and place it inside its own conditional comments targeting ie8 and only ie8/
keep the existing ie7.css style sheet and wrap it up in its own set of conditional comments targeting itself.

```
&@60;!--[if lt IE 9]&@62;
  &@60;script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"&@62;&@60;/script&@62;
  &@60;script type='text/javascript' src="js/respond.js"&@62;&@60;/script&@62;
&@60;![endif]--&@62;

&@60;!--[if IE 8]&@62;
  &@60;link href="/css/bootstrap-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet"&@62;
&@60;![endif]--&@62;

&@60;!--[if IE 7]&@62;
  &@60;link href="/css/bootstrap-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet"&@62;
&@60;![endif]--&@62;
```

2). keep ie7.css, create new styles for ie8 within ie7.css file, but you have to target one of the ie versions with a hack, specific to that version. you can read all about it, and view examples here:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie7-ie8-css-hacks/

Comment: I can use hack, but that is not the point (and not a good solution in my case). Solution which I use should work - it's only about queries. I don't want to create additional css files. I just want bootstrap to work as it should.

Comment: you are missing the point(s). not good? optimal is a frame of reference, but not good? you're already implementing the same features in your document, so its good enough for you. you "just want" bootstrap to work...again, i don't use bootstrap so i can't tell you, but if that is their markup, then you did something to break it. pretty sure they ship functional code. more to the point, you didn't even answer my questions in regards to the ie7 style sheet being pointed at ie8.